# What is max_prune_time in MemoryStore?

Tags: ruby, caching, activesupport

In the initialize method of [MemoryStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html), `max_prune_time` can be passed as an option.

What is the purpose of it?

Also, 
`@max_prune_time = options[:max_prune_time] || 2`

What is the default unit? Seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max_prune_time` is the maximum time in seconds Rails would spend to free memory, by deleting old entries if the cache store runs out of memory. See the implementation of the `prune` method for details:

```
def prune(target_size, max_time = nil)
  # ...
  start_time = Time.now
  cleanup
  instrument(:prune, target_size, :from => @cache_size) do
    keys = synchronize{ @key_access.keys.sort{|a,b| @key_access[a].to_f <=> @key_access[b].to_f} }
    keys.each do |key|
      delete_entry(key, options)
      return if @cache_size <= target_size || (max_time && Time.now - start_time > max_time)
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```